# Nginx logs in Gitlab are extremely large

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

The logs that are coming out from Gitlab are extremely large manly the Nginx access log, 2.7gb per week. I've looked through the gitlab.rc config and on the gitlab wiki to try to find a setting I can set to reduce the log file but I have no been able to find anything. Gitlab is running in a docker container with docker compose. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in [`gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf) a typical nginx configuration used by GitLab

Try and add an [nginx log level directive](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/) to that file

```
error_log logs/error.log error;
```

See [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/logs.html#using-a-custom-nginx-log-format) as an example of nginx setting configuration.

That would log only errors, which should reduce considerably the size of nginx logs.